# How can the user report someone based on his location?

Tags: support

<s>I have been downvoted because of the reason that someone (my friend, or someone from my IP address; I use Wi-Fi) upvoted my posts somehow.</s>

Can I know how can we get the users who are more likely to be attached to our data somehow, the one's with the same IP address, so that we could tell them not to bother! As it's not helping; it's a downvote.

Secondly, I wanted to know how to know if someone else posts the same answer? I have seen the system automatically preventing, but what if the link is the same code is the same, but he is using a different manner. Can we report that?

Update: This question was generally answer by a moderator on another post, because which this question gets this much down votes for being vague and unclear question. Sorry about that.

Comment: You're making a whole lot of assumptions here...

Comment: Please next time ask one question per post. That works much better in Q&A sites such as those from the Stack Exchange family. Thanks!

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn brother you can see now. On my post there are -4 -4 -5 -3 votes. On this post (question) every other post is being 4 5. My objection is not towards them, instead its for me. Why? Is it some kind of location based hatred? :/ I was following rules, I was explaining the question. And still!

Comment: I think this question is being asked in very bad faith. Everything I see is clear enough that I can't imagine how you don't know *exactly* who was voting for your posts.

Comment: If I did know, why do you think I have not asked him to down vote? Its me who is in trouble now. I am not able to ask new questions.

Comment: You did not ask anyone to down vote, and the person in question did *not* down vote; *Stack Overflow Staff* removed those votes. But *you already know that*...

Comment: I don't know, so how can I ask them to? However the answer was accepted. Being a moderator, you can close this post! I got the answers from a post below.

Comment: Didn't you already [admit your friends upvoted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fcDkf.png)?

Comment: That agree was for my IP friends, not the one's whom I pay for candy!

Comment: As an aside: see [How do comment `@replies` work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) if you want to be sure people like @Andrew read your reply.

Comment: So, as you acknowledge; you *do know* who was voting for you. So, your question here is disingenuous. Or... silly. Just walk down the hall and tell them to stop voting for you. And do it quickly, because... well....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I know how can we get the users who are more likely to be attached to our data somehow, the one's with same IP, so that we could tell them not to bother!

There is no way for any user to know the source of any votes cast on their posts. Voting is anonymous.

> As its not help its a downvote.

Its not a downvote. Its a un-upvote. The rep that you gained from the initial upvote has been nullified, hence the net being a change of +0.

> Secondly I wanted to know how to know if someone else posts the same answer? I have seen the system automatically preventing, but what if the link is same code is same but he is using a different manner. Can we report that?

It is entirely possible for two people to think of the same solution at the same time. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: No actually I was trying to say that the help will cause a downvote. Up-vote gives me points, down-votes get me into trouble.

Comment: To be frank, lots of un-upvotes will also get you into (worse) trouble. I would suggest restricting access to your WiFi, since you seem to have a lot of friends in the vicinity of your router.

Comment: Yeah this would be the idea! Preventing others to upvote me. Well thanks anyways :)

Comment: @AsheeshR I laughed and laughed and laughed at the comment about the friends on the router ;)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan - When I asked you previously if you were on a shared IP address you said ["there is no other user from this IP"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193648/i-cannot-ask-question#comment606955_193648) but now you are saying that other users of StackOverflow also use your WiFi? In that case your ban may well be due to the quality of posts coming from your IP generally.

Answer (score 7):

> I have been downvoted because of the reason that someone … upvoted my posts somehow.
>   […]
>   we could tell them not to bother! As its not help its a downvote.

That is not how it works. If serial or "favoritism" downvotes are removed, they are simply *reversed* as if the upvote never happened. They are not converted into downvotes.

So yes, you should ask your friends and people sharing your Wi-Fi to stop going through and upvoting all of your posts. I can't imagine why you need the website's help to obtain a list of your friends and the people on your local Wi-Fi network. Wi-Fi has a range of ~20 feet. You can walk around and *see* these people and *talk* to them. You know. [IRL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_life).

But you don't have to. They can keep doing it, and their votes will keep getting removed. The [automatic vote indicator script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) doesn't really care one way or the other. You just won't gain any benefit from it. And you'll see a lot of "serial upvoting reversed" messages in your reputation history.

> I wanted to know how to know if someone else posts the same answer? I have seen the system automatically preventing…

Yes, the system will step in and prevent questions that are exact duplicates. I'm not sure if it does this for answers or not, but I do know that an automatic flag is raised for review by moderators and trusted community members. This is sufficient to address the majority of cases where someone copies-and-pastes someone else's answer. If it becomes a consistent problem that cannot be handled by a simple comment, a moderator can step in and send that user a private message. Every contribution is time-stamped, so it's trivial to see who was "first".

This information is not, however, available directly to you. Why should it be? You should let someone else handle it. This kind of thing always goes over better when it comes from a disinterested third-party. That keeps it from being taken personally. "Y U STEAL MY ANSWER?!" isn't going to end well.

> what if the link is same code is same but he is using a different manner. Can we report that?

You do have to be careful. Unless your answer contains a lot of detailed information and explanation, it is rather likely that someone else came up with the same solution independently. Especially if they are only posted a few minutes apart.

There are only so many ways to skin a cat, and there are only so many answers to a question. Lots of code is going to look similar. That doesn't necessarily mean foul.

But if you do suspect something fishy is going on, you can flag the suspected post for moderator attention. Click the "flag" link, select the "other" option, and type a *detailed* custom message explaining your concerns. It would help to add a link to the other answer you suspect it of copying. Moderators have tools to investigate these things, and can take whatever action they deem necessary to handle it.

Comment: Actually everybody is not using this site. So I just wanted to know who! And we are not at a public place to walk either. I am at home, so its a public wifi only!  But yes, that serial voting is getting me into problems now. I can't post new questions to that website (stackoverflow) and moderators are saying that issue is the cause!

Comment: No one has confirmed that is the cause of your question ban. In fact, the [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193648/i-cannot-ask-question#comment606942_193648) [moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193648/i-cannot-ask-question#comment606972_193648) who have commented explicitly said that they *do not* think that is the cause. I also do not think it is related. @afz

Comment: Oh. Well I guess as they said: I need to wait!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan If you have questions about your question ban, the *only* way to get definitive answers about that is to [contact the staff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). However, don't expect to get details about why.

Comment: Thanks about this answer. I was expecting this help only! A link, from where I can get some help.

Comment: It is at the bottom of *every page*. Don't be helpless.